# XPath expression that returns a value if context node is first child

Tags: xml, xpath, infopath

I need an XPath expression that does the following:

- If the context node is *not* the first child, it returns blank
- If the context node is the first child then the expression should return the value of a "temp" node elsewhere in the document

  - In this example that value would be `<my:DisplayNameTemp>Green, John</my:DisplayNameTemp>`
- InfoPath only supports XPath 1.0 and does not support "Position" expressions
- I am using MS InfoPath and will use rules to apply this expression if more than one  child node is detected.

I am trying to blank a people picker in MS InfoPath if more than one user is selected. Here is my sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?mso-infoPathSolution solutionVersion="1.0.0.24" productVersion="14.0.0" PIVersion="1.0.0.0" href="file:///C:\Documents%20and%20Settings\Chris\Local%20Settings\Application%20Data\Microsoft\InfoPath\Designer3\35e8a7eff4a841a9\manifest.xsf" ?><?mso-application progid="InfoPath.Document" versionProgid="InfoPath.Document.2"?>
<my:myFields xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls" xmlns:ma="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/metadata/properties/metaAttributes" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2009/WSSList/dataFields" xmlns:q="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2009/WSSList/queryFields" xmlns:dfs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/dataFormSolution" xmlns:dms="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/documentManagement/types" xmlns:tns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/SharePointPortalServer/UserProfileService" xmlns:s1="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-09-06T15:09:43" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003" xml:lang="en-us">
    <my:group>
        <pc:Person xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls">
            <pc:DisplayName>Green, John</pc:DisplayName>
            <pc:AccountId>DOMAIN\John.Green</pc:AccountId>
            <pc:AccountType>User</pc:AccountType>
        </pc:Person><pc:Person xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls">
            <pc:DisplayName>Smith, John</pc:DisplayName>
            <pc:AccountId>DOMAIN\john.smith</pc:AccountId>
            <pc:AccountType>User</pc:AccountType></pc:Person>
        <pc:Person xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls">
            <pc:DisplayName>Public, John</pc:DisplayName>
            <pc:AccountId>DOMAIN\John.Q.Public</pc:AccountId>
            <pc:AccountType>User</pc:AccountType>
        </pc:Person><pc:Person xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls">
            <pc:DisplayName>Doe, John</pc:DisplayName>
            <pc:AccountId>DOMAIN\John.Doe</pc:AccountId>
            <pc:AccountType>User</pc:AccountType></pc:Person>
    </my:group>
    <my:DisplayNameTemp>Green, John</my:DisplayNameTemp>
    <my:AccountIdTemp>DOMAIN\John.Green</my:AccountIdTemp>
    <my:AccountTypeTemp>User</my:AccountTypeTemp>
</my:myFields>
```

If I can return a "blank" value for all but the first child then the picker will revalidate after the user takes focus off of it and only one username will be present.

I can use the following expression to retrieve the first user that was chosen with the picker: `//my:group/pc:Person[1]/pc:DisplayName`.

- I believe that I need an expression which utilizes the `|` command and the expression just mentioned above for the first child, or simply a "" for anything else.
- I believe that checking for the existence of a node in the preceding sibling might reveal which node is first without using any position expressions.

  I can't quite cobble it together.

Comment: Chris- What exactly is your context node here? The "first child" of what?

Comment: Chris, if "position expressions" aren't supported, than XPath 1.0 isn't supported.

Comment: @Jwiley Sorry for the lack of context; this expression is intended to be "housed" as the default value for the `displayname` node in MS InfoPath. MS InfoPath will then use the return value of this expression and place it in the `displayname` node. I hope that helps clarify!

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev MS InfoPath only supports certain aspects of XPath... You'd have to ask them.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
concat($yourTempNode[not($yourContextNode/preceding-sibling::*)], 
       substring(' ', 1 + boolean($yourContextNode/preceding-sibling::*))
       )
```

The first argument of `concat()` is the value of `$yourTempNode` -- if `$yourContextNode` has no preceding sibling element or nothing otherwise.

The second argument is a cpace character -- if `$yourContextNode` isn't the first child element of its parent or otherwize nothing.